# Echoing HTML BODY variables from PHP to javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I am doing the following:

```
var test = <? echo $variable; ?>
```

and I want to append test:

```
$("#div").append(test);
```

My problem is that `$variable` might have `''` or `""` **within  it self**. This means variable can be, for example

```
$variable = "<div style='some:style;'>Some test</div>"
```

So, when I put this in javascript it becomes

```
$("#div").append(<div style='some:style;'>Some test</div>)
```

without double quotes (throwing an error), which I try to improve:

```
$("#div").append("'"+<div style='some:style;'>Some test</div>+"'")
```

**which won't work either way with ' ' or " " because it breaks the specials within the string fragment**, stopping `'` or `"`... can someone walk me through how this can be done?

### EDIT

I'm sorry **MY BAD** my problem is that $variable actually has **a function called inside, so that's how it becomes:**

```
$("#div").append(<div onclick="some_function('string parameter')" style='some:style;'>Some test</div>)
```

That's it. How exactly can I do this?

Comment: `echo addslashes($variable);`

Comment: why are you using onclick with jquery?

Comment: @AndreCalenta yes addslashes($variable) should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `json_encode`:

`$variable = json_encode("<div style='some:style;'>Some test</div>");`

or with the function:

```
$variable=json_encode('<div onclick="some_function(\'string parameter\')" style="some:style;">Some test</div>');
```